# Python requests POST gives different response content than browser

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm writing a Python script to scrape a table from [this site](https://www.ambiente.gub.uy/SIH-JSF/paginas/sdh/consultaHDMCApublic.xhtml) (this is public information about ocean tide levels).

One of the stations I'd like to scrape is Punta del Este, code 83.0, in any given day. But my scripts returns a different table than the browser even when the POST request seems to have the same input.

When I fill the form in my browser, the headers and data sent to the server are these:

[image: Request Headers]

[image: Request Data]

So I wrote my script to make a POST request as it follows:

```
    url = 'https://www.ambiente.gub.uy/SIH-JSF/paginas/sdh/consultaHDMCApublic.xhtml'
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url, verify=False)

    soupGet = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    #JSESSIONID = s.cookies['JSESSIONID']
    javax_faces_ViewState = soupGet.find("input", {"type": "hidden", "name":"javax.faces.ViewState"})['value']
   

    headersSih = {
    'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    # 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=FBE5ZdMQVFrgQ-P6K_yTc1bw.dinaguasihappproduccion',
    'Faces-Request': 'partial/ajax',
    'Origin': 'https://www.ambiente.gub.uy',
    'Referer': url,
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     }

     

    ini_date = datetime.strftime(fecha0 , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    end_date = datetime.strftime(fecha0 + timedelta(days=1), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    codigo = 830

    dataSih = { 
    'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true',
    'javax.faces.source': 'formConsultaHorario:j_idt64',
    'javax.faces.partial.execute': '@all',
    'javax.faces.partial.render': 'formConsultaHorario:pnlhorarioConsulta',
    'formConsultaHorario:j_idt64': 'formConsultaHorario:j_idt64',
    'formConsultaHorario': 'formConsultaHorario',
    'formConsultaHorario:estacion_focus': '',
    'formConsultaHorario:estacion_input': codigo,
    'formConsultaHorario:fechaDesde_input': ini_date,
    'formConsultaHorario:fechaHasta_input': end_date,
    'formConsultaHorario:variables_focus': '',
    'formConsultaHorario:variables_input': '26', # Variable: H,Nivel
    'formConsultaHorario:fcal_focus': '',
    'formConsultaHorario:fcal_input': '7', # Tipo calculo: Ingresado
    'formConsultaHorario:ptiempo_focus': '',
    'formConsultaHorario:ptiempo_input': '2', #Paso de tiempo: Escala horaria
    'javax.faces.ViewState': javax_faces_ViewState,
    }

    page = s.post(url, headers=headersSih, data=dataSih)
```

However, when I do it via browser I get a table full of data, while python request returns (page.text) a table saying "No data was found".

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried changing a lots of stuff but nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on this website javascript loads the data. Requests dont activate it. If you want to get data from there use Selenium